# TensorFlow: how to make an inference graph from a TFHub module?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I have a VAE model saved as a TFHub module, in directory `path`. This model can be downloaded from 
`https://storage.googleapis.com/disentanglement_lib/unsupervised_study_v1/0.zip`. I can load it using hub.Module:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
module = hub.Module(path)
```

**Relevant information about the model**:

```
module.variables
[<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/conv2d_transpose/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/conv2d_transpose/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4, 64, 64) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/conv2d_transpose_1/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/conv2d_transpose_1/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4, 32, 64) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/conv2d_transpose_2/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/conv2d_transpose_2/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4, 32, 32) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/conv2d_transpose_3/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/conv2d_transpose_3/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4, 1, 32) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/dense/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/dense/kernel:0' shape=(10, 256) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/dense_1/bias:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/decoder/dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(256, 1024) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e1/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e1/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4, 1, 32) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e2/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e2/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4, 32, 32) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e3/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e3/kernel:0' shape=(2, 2, 32, 64) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e4/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e4/kernel:0' shape=(2, 2, 64, 64) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e5/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/e5/kernel:0' shape=(1024, 256) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/log_var/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/log_var/kernel:0' shape=(256, 10) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/means/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'module_1/encoder/means/kernel:0' shape=(256, 10) dtype=float32>]
```

```
module.get_input_info_dict(signature='gaussian_encoder') 
module.get_input_info_dict(signature='decoder') 
module.get_input_info_dict(signature='reconstructions')
{'images': <hub.ParsedTensorInfo shape=(?, 64, 64, 1) dtype=float32 is_sparse=False>}
{'latent_vectors': <hub.ParsedTensorInfo shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32 is_sparse=False>}
{'images': <hub.ParsedTensorInfo shape=(?, 64, 64, 1) dtype=float32 is_sparse=False>}
```

```
module.get_output_info_dict(signature='gaussian_encoder') 
module.get_output_info_dict(signature='decoder') 
module.get_output_info_dict(signature='reconstructions')
{'mean': <hub.ParsedTensorInfo shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32 is_sparse=False>, 'logvar': <hub.ParsedTensorInfo shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32 is_sparse=False>}
{'images': <hub.ParsedTensorInfo shape=(?, 64, 64, 1) dtype=float32 is_sparse=False>}
{'images': <hub.ParsedTensorInfo shape=(?, 64, 64, 1) dtype=float32 is_sparse=False>}
```

**Building an inference graph**:

This VAE was trained on *dsprites*. Let's say I get a subset of *dsprites* of size 2, so that I have a dataset of dimensions:

```
dataset.shape
(2, 64, 64, 1)
```

where dataset is a numpy array.

1. How do I use module to encode input images from dataset into *mean* and *logvar*?
2. How do I use module to reconstruct input images from dataset, i.e., encode and decode?

**Source of related information**:

[How to use TensorFlow Hub with code examples](https://medium.com/@prasad.pai/how-to-use-tensorflow-hub-with-code-examples-9100edec29af)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link provides the necessary documentation [www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_signatures/images](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_signatures/images). The following code does the encoding:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub 
path = '../0/model/tfhub'

module = hub.Module(path)
outputs = module(dict(images=dataset), signature='gaussian_encoder',as_dict=True)
logvar = outputs["logvar"]
mean = outputs["mean"]

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run([logvar, mean])
```

The reconstruction can be done analogously.